# How can I determine if a function is onto if the codomain is not specified?

Tags: functions

A question asks "Is $f(x)=x^2$ an onto function or not?" Here the domain and codomain are not mentioned specifically, so what codomain should I consider?

Comment: I don't know. Surjectivity is a pretty silly concept if you ask me

Comment: I'd answer "it depends". By the way, the domain is not specified either.

Comment: I think that is exactly the point of this exercise. I suggest you consider sets where the function is bijective and sets where it is only surjective. Assuming  $x$ is from a field.

Comment: If a proper context is lacking then this question cannot be answered. You might answer (and mention examples) that there are situations in which the function is onto and also situations in which the function is not onto.

Comment: The function only takes non-negative values!

Comment: @k1.M How do you know?  If the domain isn't specified, it is impossible to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a case like this, I would assume the domain and codomain are intended to be the real numbers unless you are taking a complex analysis class.

Comment: In this case the function is not surjective because the range is $\mathbb{R}^+\ne\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1):

It's likely the intended domain is all real numbers such that the expression makes sense, and the intended codomain is the set of real numbers. This function would be neither injective nor surjective under these assumptions.

However, the domain and codomain should always be specified. This is especially true when discussing injectivity and surjectivity, because one can make any function an injection by modifying the domain and a surjection by modifying the codomain. For example:

$$
f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}; \quad f(x)=x^2 \quad \text{is neither injective nor surjective}
$$
$$
f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}; \quad f(x)=x^2 \quad \text{is injective but not surjective}
$$
$$
f:\mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty); \quad f(x)=x^2 \quad \text{is surjective but not injective}
$$
$$
f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty); \quad f(x)=x^2 \quad \text{is both injective and surjective}
$$

This example demonstrates that the notion of injectivity and surjectivity rely just as much on the domain and codomain, respectively, as they rely on the rule defining the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is a poorly worded question.  In order to define a function, we need three ingredients: the domain, the codomain, and some rule for mapping the domain into the codomain.  Without those data, it is impossible to answer the question.